# Database Objects do not exists after Flyway migrate()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, flyway, hikaricp

In our Spring-Boot service we are using H2 DB in the Unit Tests and the DB Objects are created using Flyway migration scripts and also the test input data is inserted using such scripts. In the @AfterEach method of each testcase all the DB Objects are dropped and we would like to re-create the DB objects and insert the required test data in the @BeforEach method. (I know it isn't the best approach but we do have our reasons to do it on this way.) For the re-creation of the DB objects we call the Flyway migration programmatically.

The problem is, that however the migration is performed successfully, the created DB objects does not exist after that or at least the are not visible.

The code called in the @BeforeEach method:
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

```
@Value( "${mySvc.dbAppSchema}" )
private String dbSchema;

@Value( "${spring.flyway.url}" )
private String dbUrl;

@Value( "${spring.flyway.user}" )
private String dbUser;

@Value( "${spring.flyway.password}" )
private String dbPwd;

@Value( "${spring.flyway.locations}" )
private String dbMigrLocations;

public boolean tableExists( String schema, String table ) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    ResultSet rset = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, schema, table, null);
    return rset.next();
}

@Transactional
public void recreateDBTables() throws FlywayException, SQLException {
    if ( ! tableExists( dbSchema, "SAMPLE_TABLE" ) ) {
        Flyway flyway =  Flyway.configure().dataSource( dataSource ).locations( dbMigrLocations ).load();
        flyway.migrate();
    }
    
    if ( tableExists( dbSchema, "SAMPLE_TABLE" ) )
        log.info( "Tables have been created!!!" );
    else {
        log.info( "Tables still not exist!!!!");
    }
}
```

I can see in the log, that each required SQL script is executed (one of the includes CREATE TABLE SAMPLE TABLE...)

We are using Hikaricp as well.

Relevant configuration properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.autoCommit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=${mySvc.dbAppSchema}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:${mySvc.dbAppSchema};MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${mySvc.dbAppSchema};DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=${mySvc.dbAppSchema}
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:${mySvc.dbAppSchema};MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${mySvc.dbAppSchema};DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.flyway.user=${mySvc.dbAppSchema}
spring.flyway.password=pwd
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:src/test/resources/db/flyway/allTCs
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Any idea?

Comment: You need to configure h2 so that changes are not automatically deleted. Flyway will honor whatever h2 configuration you have used. Looks like setting DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 should do it. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224338/keep-h2-in-memory-database-between-connections